how to recover an account with lost password on Linux mint
My Linux Mint computer running XFCE is not accepting my password. I do not have another account configured on the computer to login with. I could load the OS from USB and do a re-install, but I'd rather not.
How can I reset/recover my account in Linux Mint?

Since it turned out to be a hardware issue you may want to remove the linux and linux-mint tags, they have nothing to do with the problem.

I discovered the problem is the keyboard has a dead key. So the solution is to go in the onscreen keyboard, which is the 'onboard' app.

Please mark your answer as accepted solution. This'll make it easier for others (and the algorithms) to find your solution.

@mtak I'm not sure that discovering one has faulty hardware (or using a workaround) is a solution to the problem statement in the question.
